# Использование интерфейся для Unit of Work

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, инспекция-кода, asp.net-web-api

[GitHub-ссылка на проект](https://github.com/derkode/MonitDbTable)

К собеседованию было дано тестовое задание:

> Create a web application that will monitor changes on a SQL table
>   using SignalR Requirements
>
> 1) The SQL table should have the following definition: CREATE TABLE
>   DevTest( [ID] int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, [CampaignName] varchar(255)
>   NULL, [Date] datetime NULL, [Clicks} int NULL, [Conversions] int NULL,
>   [Impressions] int NULL, [AffiliateName] varchar(255) NULL )
>
> 2) All data access should adhere to the repository and unit of work
>   design patterns
>
> 3) There should be a view that implements SignalR and displays the
>   changes to the SQL table in real time.
>
> 4) There should be a view that allows the user to make changes to the
>   DevTest table (insert, update, delete)

, где как видите, одним из условий было использование паттерна `Unit of Work`.

---

Вот часть моего решения *(с полным решением вы можете ознакомиться по ссылке выше/в конце этого поста)* касаемо `UoW`:

**IRepository.cs**

```
namespace MonitDbTable.Interfaces
{
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        T Get(int id);
        void Add(T item);
        void Update(T item);
        void Delete(int id);
    }
}
```

**DevTest.cs**

```
namespace MonitDbTable.Models
{
    public class DevTest
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]        
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

        public int? Clicks { get; set; }
        public int? Conversions { get; set; }
        public int? Impressions { get; set; }
        public string AffiliateName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DevTestRepository.cs**

```
namespace MonitDbTable.Repositories
{
    public class DevTestRepository : IRepository<DevTest>
    {
        private readonly string _connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString;

        private DevTestContext db;
        public DevTestRepository(DevTestContext db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }
        public void Add(DevTest item)
        {
            db.DevTests.Add(item);
        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            var item = db.DevTests.Find(id);
            db.DevTests.Remove(item);
        }

        public DevTest Get(int id)
        {
            return db.DevTests.Find(id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<DevTest> GetAll()
        {
            var devTests = new List<DevTest>();
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Id], [CompanyName], [Date], [Clicks], [Conversions], [Impressions], [AffiliateName] FROM [dbo].[DevTests]", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;

                    var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {                        
                        devTests.Add(item: new DevTest
                        {
                            Id = (int)reader["Id"],
                            CompanyName = reader["CompanyName"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)reader["CompanyName"] : "",
                            Date = reader["Date"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"]) : (DateTime?)null,
                            Clicks = reader["Clicks"] != DBNull.Value ? (int)reader["Clicks"] : 0,
                            Conversions = reader["Conversions"] != DBNull.Value ? (int)reader["Conversions"] : 0,
                            Impressions = reader["Impressions"] != DBNull.Value ? (int)reader["Impressions"] : 0,
                            AffiliateName = reader["AffiliateName"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)reader["AffiliateName"] : ""
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            return devTests;
        }

        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                DevTestsHub.SendMessages();
            }
        }

        public void Update(DevTest item)
        {
            db.Entry<DevTest>(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

**UnitOfWork.cs**

```
namespace MonitDbTable.Repositories
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        private DevTestContext db = new DevTestContext();
        private DevTestRepository dtRepository;

        public DevTestRepository DevTests
        {
            get
            {
                if (dtRepository == null)
                    dtRepository = new DevTestRepository(db);
                return dtRepository;
            }
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        private bool disposed = false;

        public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    db.Dispose();
                }
                this.disposed = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### ЗАМЕЧАНИЕ ИНТЕРВЬЮЕРА

Интервьюер поставил мне два плюса (2+) и 4- по этому заданию. И один из минусов гласит:

> Didn't use interface for unit of work

Собственно именно по этому "минусу" я и хочу чтобы вы меня проконсультировали и помогли разобраться в том **как правильно использовать UoW**.

---

### Мои знания и попытки

- в тех статьях, где я знакомился с этим паттерном, как-то не делался
  акцент на использовании интерфейсов *или я не обратил внимание*;
- я и не до конца понял, что именно означает эта строчка замечания:
  имеется ввиду необходимость объявления интерфейса `IUnitOfWork` или
  автор имел ввиду в класс `UnitOfWork` внедрить зависимость от
  репозитория `DevTestRepository`?
- в Интернете не так-то и много статей где можно встретить **I**UnitOfWork.
  К примеру, есть один пост на [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/276/interface-for-unit-of-work-pattern-and-repository-pattern). Но думаю этот случай у
  парня очень специфичный, так как у него там `IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }` в качестве свойства у `interface IRepository<T>`.

Но одно я исправил - внедрил зависимость от контекста:

```
public UnitOfWork(DevTestContext db)
{
    this.db = db;
}
```

Иначе "не возможно" было тестировать `WebApi-методы`, которые обращаются к БД через `UoW`.

[GitHub-ссылка на проект](https://github.com/derkode/MonitDbTable)

Comment: Unit of Work - это логическая транзакция применяемая к бизнес-модели, т.е. этапная процедура проверки и изменения бизнес-сущностей с последующей операцией Commit. Несколько напоминает транзакции в реляционных БД.

Comment: @Bulson, ... и у меня в качестве Commit выступает метод `Save()`, так?